# Use Stack Exchange icon for Stack Exchange blog posts in the Community Bulletin

Tags: feature-request, blog, community-bulletin

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/ is used to host global Stack Exchange blog posts and is using favicon of Stack Exchange itself. All good.

However, when published in the bulletin, the Meta Stack Exchange icon is used for some reason:

> [image]

Can it be changed please to using the "full" icon?

> [image]

Comment: The Meta icon is so empty. Just like Meta.

Comment: We should probably just kill the blog in favor of MSE posts. Problem solved...

Comment: @Shog9 yup, that would work.